# Pandas: How to get position of columns?

Tags: pandas, position, multiple-columns

I need help to get the position of the column or another way to read in the column two step left of the column *Spannung*.

```
Exceldata = pd.read_excel(str(Dateien[0]), header=[2])
print Dateien[0]
Spannung = Exceldata.columns[Exceldata.columns.str.contains('Spannung effektiv L1')]
print Spannung
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the position number of a column in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998923/how-to-get-the-position-number-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html#pandas.Index.get_loc)

So:

```
pos = Exceldata.columns.get_loc(Spannung[0])
```

then you can index left:

```
other_col = Exceldata.columns[pos -2]
```

Example:

```
In [169]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['hello','world','python','pandas','Spannung effektiv L1', 'asdas'])
spannung = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Spannung')]
spannung

Out[169]:
Index(['Spannung effektiv L1'], dtype='object')

In [178]:
pos = df.columns.get_loc(spannung[0])
df.columns[pos-2]

Out[178]:
'python'
```

Comment: Because Spannung looks like that

Comment: Index([u'Spannung effektiv L1 (V)'], dtype='object')

Comment: Sorry I forgot you get an `IndexArray` you need to index into the `IndexArray` to return a Scalar, see my edit

Comment: I just wanted to ask you how it goes. Did you get it?